# Remove desktop shortcut after uninstall uwp on windows

Tags: uwp, uninstallation

I install uwp app and place a shorcut to desktop via "shell:AppsFolder" and choosing right icon app and "Create shortcut", but after uninstall the app, the desktop shortcut remains...is it possible somehow from uwp side to remove all shortcuts to the uninstalled app?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not even possible for non-UWP apps to locate and remove arbitrary shortcuts. They are a 1-way link.

Comment: Yeah, i didnt find a way either...